# How do i start runing a file system mini filter

Tags: minifilter, filter-driver

I'm new to mini filter programming , i compiled the Windows swapBuffers mini filter example (with a bit extra dbgprinting) and tried to run it on windows xp and windows 7.

i tried to use th install option of the inf file and nothing happend (i checked with dbgView - ther is no printing and with `fltmc.exe` - there is no new mini filtering).

i tried use fltmc.exe load option , i got `load failed with error: 0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified` (even thet i in the minifilter folder and double checked the path and the spelling).

i tried to use `sc create my_filter type= filesys binPath=...` and when i tried `sc start my_filter` i got a blue screen (got the same results when trying to load with OSR louder).

can sombody please help me to start runing my first "hello world" minifilter?

thank you
pit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do check file path info in inf file. For your initial error.

Comment: I did it, (2 times...) ther is nothing rung with the path

Comment: If the driver is self signed and your environment is 64bit then disable signature enforcement. But what's bsod error code your getting.

Comment: i get `*** STOP: 0x0000007f (0x0000000d, 0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000)` in windows xp(32bit) and in win7(64bit) i get `StartService FAILED 1275: This driver has been blocked from loading` (this errors are when i try to load the minifilter using the sc method)

Comment: when i try with osr loader i get in win7 `target driver was not loaded operation return error code 0x4fd` (in xp i get also a blue screen)

Comment: On Windows 7 64bit do check driver binary as 64 bit build not 32 bit.

Comment: still getting 0x4fd , but when i try with the `sc` method i get `windows can't varify the digital signiture ...` (i compile the driver on win 7 with visual studio and try it on vmware virtual win 7 )

Comment: You need to install test certificate.Also refer following site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/how-to-test-sign-a-driver-package

Answer (score 0):

Build you driver for x86 or x64 do not use universal driver for windows 7 it is for windows 10. now set the bcdedit -set testsigning on fand -set debug on. reboot your system. now after reboot hit f8 and go for disable signing option.

after system up, make sure .sys and inf in same dir i assume you have written ur inf properly. now install your driver by inf. open cmd elevated mode type 
fltmc load drivername without .sys. filter will load without a problem.

If problem persist then check your inf file for correction.

Hope this may help.

:)

Answer (score 0):

win7

attach kernel debugger

then

pnputil -a infname.inf

sc query servicename

should say stopped

sc start servicename

should see it load in debugger if verbose is on (alt+ctrl+v)